# How is abrasive footing achieved?

Tags: horses

While learning about how many tools are used during hoof care and to just how extensive trimming and shoeing is, I would like to know how abrasive footing achieved. According to this [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe), these include rubber, plastic, magnesium, titanium, or copper hooves. Moreover, I inquire about abrasive footing and wether it is beneficial for horses lifestyles or for events.

Thank you in advance for teaching me further on a [farriers'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farrier) routine work.

Comment: you might take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe to learn about what materials are used.you might want to narrow down your question as it is now it is very broad,and it is realy not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Also note that there are no "rubber, plastic, magnesium, titanium, or copper **hooves**", these would be shoes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Abrasive footing" isn't achieved as such, it's a situation that's dealt with.

"Abrasive footing" is a ground surface that has the effect of abrading away the hoof material - so that's tarmac road surfaces, stone, gravel etc.

Whether this is beneficial for the horse or not is debatable in the same way as it is for us humans - walking on sidewalks gradually wears out our shoes, but we get to where we need to go faster (and cleaner) than walking on mud.

There's many resources on the internet looking at the decisions for what material to use for horseshoes.

[How to pick the right shoe for the job](http://www.elizabeththefarrier.com/horseshoe-selection-how-to-pick-the-right-shoe-for-the-job/)  is just one of them.

For different footings (ground materials for horses), there's other resources

[Example - Footing material options](https://www.whatcomcd.org/sites/default/files/farm_assist/smallfarm/Footing%20Material%20Options%20(WCD).pdf) (PDF)